# Date Format script Progress 4GL

Tags: date-format, progress-4gl, openedge

`mvl_dtmov` is my data attribute which I would like to output in `dd/MM/YYYY` format. Does anyone know how to define it?

```
DEF STREAM st1.
OUTPUT STREAM st1 TO c:\temp\movimentos.csv.
ASSIGN SESSION:DATE-FORMAT = "mdy".

FOR EACH multipos.mp_mvlj  NO-LOCK:

   PUT STREAM st1 UNFORMATTED multipos.mp_mvlj.mvl_dtmov ";" SKIP.

END.

OUTPUT STREAM st1 CLOSE.
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you set date-format to "mdy" if you want "dmy" ?
Use dmy and set year-offset to 0 to force 4 digit year

```
SESSION:DATE-FORMAT = "dmy".
SESSION:YEAR-OFFSET = 0.
```